# Is there a reason to make my online account passwords strong?

Tags: passwords, login, password-protection

This question is about online passwords only. (not encryption etc)

I know it is easy to bruteforce a short password or look up a hash in a rainbow table. But considering how Google, Facebook or online banking sites make you fill out captchas/lock you out after a few bad attempts/require two-factor authentication, does it really make sense to have strong passwords for online accounts?

I don't mean using garbage like kitten123 etc. But even two Diceware words seem plenty to me.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The more sensitive the login the stronger I make my password, but that's just my logic. It never hurts to have more layers of difficulty when accessing your more critical accounts.

Comment: That is how I think about it, too (and hence, have relatively strong pws), but am not sure if that is really necessary if the companies have good security measures in place. (They mostly do, and the ones that don't are not "important" - that is, there is little to lose if your account gets hacked into. Like random forums, etc)

Answer (score 3):

## Yes, of course!

There's no question about it.

In a vast majority of implementations passwords are the only security measure that protects your account.

The other mechanisms you mention: captcha or lock-out time on password retries, only add a small obstacle to the channel you are using to login. They have no meaning if the password database was stolen and brute-forced offline.

Second factor authentication adds security to the authenticating channel but it should not replace the main means of authentication whether in full or in part.

These additional measures are often badly implemented and easy to overcome in targeted attacks.

An easy test for that is what you need to do to replace/reinitiate the 2nd factor means. If it's an in-person visit to a bank branch where you get a new printed pad or security token, then you might assume it is safe, if it's a call to a call-centre and providing your address and your mother's maiden name after which 2nd factor is disabled for you to login with password only, then it's useless.

Users also do not take precautions to separate the 2nd factor from the main means of authenticating. For example use browser + stored password + one-time code generator on a single mobile device.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did not consider the possibility of the password db getting stolen. But even then, the likelihood of a random specific account getting compromised seems unlikely to me: (1) the hackers have limited time (attacks like this get publicized quickly), (2) there are a lot of accounts to bruteforce, making it unlikely they get to any specific account (3) even the bruteforcing is not trivial since the password is "correct horse", not "monkey".

Comment: On resetting two-factor authentication. Suppose the hacker gets locked out and calls in with all the info. Boom, another 10 tries. He does it a couple more times for a total of 50 guesses. It is still practically nothing, even for a very weak, 24 bit password. And he will get locked out permanently much faster than that. (Hmmm this seems like a good way if you want to brick someone's account...)